# What is wrong with the resolution of the equation?

Tags: arithmetic

I have this equation:
$$
16(n+8) = 16
$$

If i resolve the equation, i divide 16 in both sides, it will:

$$ (n+ 8) = 1 $$

After, $$ n = -7 $$

But, if i divide all terms by `8`, the `n` value is **different**:

$$16\frac{(n + 8)}8 = \frac{16}8$$
$$ 2(\frac n8 + 1) = 2 $$
$$ (\frac n8 + 1 ) = 1 $$
$$ \frac n8 = 0 ,  n = 0$$

What is the error, i suposse it is a mistake of the basic laws of algebra

Comment: So $2\times 2=4$, and if we divide by $2$, then $1\times 1=2$?

Comment: You divided the left side twice by $8$. You divided $16$ and $n+8$ by $8$ which is a division by $64$ , not by $8$. If we had the sum $16+(n+8)$ , the division by $8$ would actually give $2+(n/8+1)$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error is there: 2(n/8 + 1) = 2, you don't have to divide n by 8.

You have already divided 16 by 8 on the LHS.

The correct way is:

$$16(n + 8) = 16  \iff \frac{16}{8}(n + 8) = \frac{16}{8}\iff 2(n + 8) = 2$$

Comment: Why? , you can give me the name of the this law, please

Comment: @EduardoCampos it's the" Law of Cancellation of the Product". Try with some number to convince yourself :).

Comment: It's the associative law for multiplication.

Comment: oh, thanks all for help me

Comment: You are welcome, please set as solved if it' ok.